# Send email from outlook by including dataframe as table in R

Tags: r, outlook, html-email, xtable, rdcomclient

I have a dataframe as shown below. I am then converting the dataframe into an html table.

```
# Use RDCOMClient to send email from outlook
library(RDCOMClient)
# Use xtable to convert dataframe into html table
library(xtable)

# Create dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(mtcars[1:3,1:3])

# Create HTML object
df_html <- xtable(df)
```

Now, I am sending an email from outlook using the wonderful solution given in the email thread [Sending email in R via outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811679/sending-email-in-r-via-outlook)

```
## init com api
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
## create an email 
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
## configure  email parameter 
outMail[["To"]] = "dest@dest.com"
outMail[["subject"]] = "some subject"
outMail[["body"]] = df_html
## send it                     
outMail$Send()
```

For the body of my email, I want the data frame df which I want to attach as a html table. When I execute the above code, I get the below error message.

```
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, "body", value = list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8), cyl = c(6,  : 
  Can't attach the RDCOMServer package needed to create a generic COM object
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘RDCOMServer’
```

When I change the line `outMail[["body"]] = df_html` to `outMail[["body"]] = paste0(df_html)`, I get the email but the output does not come as a table. It comes as shown below in my outlook.

```
c(21, 21, 22.8), c(6, 6, 4), c(160, 160, 108)
```

I want this to be a table. How can i achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Dear experts, any suggestions on how to solve this problem in R?

Comment: I have a partial solution to this problem which has provided in the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248728/html-table-output-formatting-when-sending-email-from-microsoft-outlook-using-r. But then I ran into another problem for which I have asked a new question as seen in the link above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a solution to pasting a dataframe as an HTML table in Microsoft outlook. This is using the `xtable` package. Part of the solution credit goes to @lukeA from here - [How to show an excel worksheet in outlook body by R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282094/how-to-show-an-excel-worksheet-in-outlook-body-by-r)

Below is the solution.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(xtable)

x <- head(mtcars)
y <- print(xtable(x), type="html", print.results=FALSE)

body <- paste0("<html>", y, "</html>")

OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
outMail[["To"]] = "test@test.com"
outMail[["subject"]] = "TEST EMAIL"
outMail[["HTMLbody"]] = body
outMail$Send()
```

This is how the output looks like in Microsoft outlook.

[image: Screenshot from Microsoft Outlook]

Comment: I followed the steps but the email came in in a weird html format instead of what you showed

Comment: I got this to work. I was using ```outMail[["body"]] = body``` instead of ```outMail[["HTMLbody"]] = body```