# How to attach any file (xlsx, xls, txt, jpg etc.) in Outlook auto mail push thru R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to send an Outlook mail thru R by using RDCOMClient and trying to attach an Excel file in it but getting an error.

**Below is my script:**

```
library(RDCOMClient)
## init com API
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
## Create an email 
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
## Configure email parameter 
outMail[["To"]] = "ashishpatil@orientindia.net"
outMail[["cc"]] = "atulkadam@orientindia.net"
outMail[["subject"]] = paste0("RE: Update your Todays date",format(Sys.Date(),"%d-%m-%y"),"Timesheet.")
outMail[["body"]] = "Dear Sir/Madam,
       Please find below the CMS Application - Total Count of Records Uploaded Status:"
outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add("C:/Users/atulkadam/OneDrive - Orient Technologies Pvt. Ltd/Atul/Time Sheet/atul kadam",Sys.Date(),".xlsx")
## Send it                     
outMail$Send()
```

when I run the Attachments code It shows me the below error.

```
Error in.COM(x, name, ...) : 
 [Error code][1] Can't attach the RDCOMServer package needed to create a generic COM object
```

Comment: even tried in another way also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282094/how-to-show-an-excel-worksheet-in-outlook-body-by-r 
but it also shows me an error. please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

The below Code works for me;

```
library(RDCOMClient)
## init com API
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
## Create an email 
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
## Configure email parameter 
path_to_attachment <- paste0("C:/Users/atulkadam/OneDrive - Orient Technologies Pvt. Ltd/Atul/Time Sheet/atul kadam")

outMail[["To"]] = "atulkadam@orientindia.net"
outMail[["cc"]] = "ashishpatil@orientindia.net"
outMail[["subject"]] = paste0("RE: Update your Todays date",format(Sys.Date(),"%d-%m-%y"),"Timesheet.")

outMail[["body"]] = "Dear Sir/Madam,
       Please find below the CMS Application - Total Count of Records Uploaded Status:"
outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add(paste0(path_to_attachment,format(Sys.Date(),"%d-%m-%Y"),".xlsx"))
## Send it                     
outMail$Send()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).